# How to create table shown in figure?

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like the below

[image]

I have tried like this

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline\text{Parabola}&\text{Curve}&\text{Focus}&\text{Dirextrix}&\text{Vertex}\\\hline $x^2=4py$&\text{up, if}\thinspace $p>0$\newline\text{down, if}\thinspace $p<0$&&&\\\hline$y^2=4px$&&&&\\\hline&&&&\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
```

But there is problem in all each column which I am facing except the first column. Color is not necessary.

Comment: What about this table are you trying to replicate? The colors? The fact that all 5 columns appear to have (more or less) the same width? The exact same font? Please be specific.

Comment: For a multi-line cell, use a `p{...}` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}\begin{tabular}{|c|r@{\ }l|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}\textbf{Parabola}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Curve}}&\textbf{Focus}&\textbf{Dirextrix}&\textbf{Vertex}\\\hline 
$x^2=4py$&up, if &$p>0$&$F(0,p)$&$y=-p$&$V(0,0)$\\
& down, if&$p<0$&$F(0,p)$&$y=-p$&$V(0,0)$\\\hline
$y^2=4px$&right, if&$p>0$&$F(0,p)$&$y=-p$&$V(0,0)$\\
& left, if&$p<0$&$F(0,p)$&$y=-p$&$V(0,0)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Answer (score 3):

This should be replica of your image in question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}          % coloring first row in table
\usepackage{array, multirow}        % for multirow cells in the first columns
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}    % for additional vertical space around cells' contents
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{| c | r @{\ } >{$}Ol<{$} | >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} |}
 {$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!20}
\textbf{Parabola}   
        &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Curve}}&\textbf{Focus}    
                    & \textbf{Dirextrix} & \textbf{Vertex}  \\
        \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$x^2=4py$}
    & up, if    & p>0   & F(0,p)    & y=-p & V(0,0,)    \\
        & down, if  & p<0   & F(0,p)    & y=-p & V(0,0,)    \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$y^2=4px$}
    & right, if & p>0  & F(0,p)     & y=-p & V(0,0,)    \\
    & left, if  & p<0  & F(0,p)     & y=-p & V(0,0,)    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir it is not running in premeable here with me.

Comment: @NoorAslam, I test provide code. It works and produce showed image. You probably change something in my code.